# Why is lagrangian mechanics replaced by path integrals?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral

The path integral includes the action:

$$\int \mathcal{D[\phi]} e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int d^4x \mathcal{L}[\phi]}$$

Which considers all possible field configurations, whether they satisfy Euler-Lagrange equations or not. We then can use this path integral to construct the probability amplitude of a field.

Everyone makes it seem path integrals replace lagrangian mechanics. I'm not entirely convinced, because the lagrangian is a mathematical construct.

Why can't we construct a new lagrangian that includes all of this? After all, the lagrangian is our construct and we can make it produce any field. Why don't we construct a lagrangian of the probability amplitude?

Comment: What do you mean by "lagrangian of the probability amplitude"?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726311/2451

Comment: Hi Habouz. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Here I'm hitting my gray area in this field because I'm new to QFT. Anyways, in Quantum Mechanics, the wave function $\psi$ is a function of the position of a particle. In QFT, $\psi$ is now a function of the field $\phi$ itself (electron field for example). Can't we have a lagriangian for $\psi$, and when we minimize it, we get a differential equation to determine the probability function of a field?